# Python/Selenium: insert an iterator in the Xpath

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to insert the variable "i" on my Xpath but I'm hitting a wall.

This is my code:

```
for i in range(len(results_nbr)):
    xpath = "//*[@id='w1']/div["
    xpath += int(i)
    xpath += "]/div/div[2]/h3"

    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    elem.click()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I'm using selenium and it works fine if I have the variable in the code as below:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="w1"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/h3')
```

What is wrong with my code please? I tried int(i) and str(i) with same result.

I appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't know what is a X-Y problem. I thought that my issue is well detailled in my question. How to add the "i" variable in the code above. Your insight would be appreciated if you can can enlighten me about what's wrong with my post.

Comment: What is `results_nbr`? Also share exception log

Comment: len(results_nbr) = 31, Sorry but I have no idea what is an exception log. I'm kind of beginner in the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*First point*: use string formatting. There are a lot of available options in Python:

```
 - xpath = '//*[@id="w1"]/div[%s]/div/div[2]/h3' % i
 - xpath = '//*[@id="w1"]/div[{}]/div/div[2]/h3'.format(i)
 - xpath = f'//*[@id="w1"]/div[{i}]/div/div[2]/h3' # in Python 3.6 and later
```

*Second point*: in XPath indexing starts from `1`. So `div[0]` won't work. Try

```
for i in range(1, len(results_nbr) + 1):
    ...
```